# Paypal .Net SDK dynamic switch between Sandbox and live not working

Tags: .net, paypal, payment-gateway

I have a webapplication which contains multiple websites. Some websites must use Paypal in Sandbox mode and others in Live mode.

Because of this, i need to set the configuration (mode, clientId & secret) at runtime and not in the web.config.

The problem is that my application doesn't change the mode to live or sandbox. It keeps using the web.config setting.

I created a small console application to test.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing Paypal");
        Console.WriteLine("Test");

        Console.WriteLine(TestPaypal(true, "testClientId", "testSecret"));

        Console.WriteLine("Live");
        Console.WriteLine(TestPaypal(false, "myLiveClientId", "myLiveSecret"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string TestPaypal(bool isTest, string clientId, string secret)
    {
        try
        {
            var config = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"mode", isTest ? "sandbox" : "live"}
            };
            var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, secret, config).GetAccessToken();
            var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
            var payment = Payment.Create(apiContext, new Payment
            {
                intent = "sale",
                payer = new Payer {payment_method = "paypal"},
                transactions = new List<Transaction>
                {
                    new Transaction
                    {
                        description = "Test via Console app",
                        invoice_number = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        amount = new Amount
                        {
                            currency = "EUR",
                            total = "100.00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls
                {
                    return_url = "http://www.google.com",
                    cancel_url = "http://www.google.com"
                }
            });
            var url = payment.links.Single(o => o.rel == "approval_url");
            return url.href;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

My app.config setting looks like this

```
<paypal>
    <settings>
        <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
        <add name="clientId" value="xxx" />
        <add name="clientSecret" value="xxx" />
    </settings>
</paypal>
```

For both requests in the code, it keeps using de sandbox setting from the app.config. In this case i get a normal result for Test and an error (401 not authorized) for Live.
When i change the app.config (mode to live). I receive a 401 for the Testcall and a successfull result for Live.

So, obviously, both my credentials are correct, but the mode doesn't change at runtime.

Does anybody knows why?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours on research i found the answer myself:

Offcourse we need to set the config also on the ApiContext and not only to get the accesToken object.

The line to create the ApiContext has changed to this and now it's working

```
var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken){Config = config};
```